# How does the universal hash function that randomly generates an integer perform lookup after insertion?

Tags: algorithm, hash, hashtable, hashcode

The following demonstration was taken from the Algorithms: Design and Analysis video lecture on Coursera provided by Tim Roughgarden (phenomenal explanations btw). From what I understand, this hash function effectively returns an existing index position between 0 to n in the hash table. However, I am confounded by how this unique computation can be reverse engineered for constant time look-ups when `a` (below) is a randomized integer.

```
Let U = IP addresses (of the form (x1, x2, x3, x4)
                       with each subscript of x in  {0,1,2,...255})
Let n = a prime number
Define one hash function per 4-tuple a = (a1, a2, a3, a4)
                         with each subscript of a in {0, 1, 2,...n-1}
Define: h<sub>a : IP addresses ---> buckets        *n^4 such functions*
by h<sub>a(x1,x2,x3,x4) = (a1x1 + a2x2 + a3x3 + a4x4)

<sub> = subscript notation
```

The above equation is then computed with `modulo n` to return a position within the hash table that has a 1/n probability chance of recurrence for any different inputs within `U`. How do I retrieve that IP address location with the original IP address?

Answer (score 1):

Hashes lose information. So you cannot work backwards from the hash to the original. You store the original at the index given by its hash; you can verify that some value x is in the table by seeing whether the item at H(x) is x.

Of course, that won't work if two objects in the table have the same hash (a "collision"). Different hash-table algorithms have different strategies to deal with collisions, and for the strategy your lecturer is probably explaining, it will be useful to have another independent hash function.

Comment: Let me see if I get this straight. If the look-up is checking whether the item at H(x) is x, wouldn't that require linear time? Or are you saying that running the `item` through the different hash functions and checking the locations of the return values for `x` would guarantee retrieval, therefore I've misinterpreted randomness of `a` for patternized computations on different inputs of `U`? Thank you for your answer, btw.

Comment: @Pro:Normally, you select a single hash function for a table. Sometimes you select two. In theory, you could use as many as you like, so here's a possible collision strategy that no-one uses: (1) Select (at random, but permanently) a sequencing of all the universal hash functions: H1, H2, .... (Actually, you don't really need to create the sequence, you only need to know how to regenerate it.) To find x in the hash table, compute hashes H1(x), H2(x), ... and look in the corresponding table entry until you either find x or empty. Your task: prove that the expected number of probes is N/(N-α)...

Comment: ... which is O(1) if you limit α by growing the hash table when its occupancy gets too high.